# PHP Multiple selectform send string to database not working as intended

Tags: php, mysqli, forms

Im trying to send a string to my database depending on the answers from a multiple select question. The question has three answers, ESEA,FACEIT and Matchmaking. Depending on the answer i want to send strings to my database. The database is set up with Varchar.

The html form for handling my multiple select question looks like this:

```
<select name="multipleSelect[]" multiple>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
   <option name="esea" value="esea">ESEA</option>
   <option name="faceit" value="faceit">FaceIT</option>
   <option name="matchmaking" value="matchmaking">Matchmaking</option>
</select>
<label>What are you looking to play?</label>
```

The code for handling the form look like this:

```
$esea = '';
$faceit = '';
$matchmaking = '';
foreach ( $_POST['multipleSelect'] as $value ) {
    if ( $value == 'esea' )        { $esea = 'ESEA';  }
    if ( $value == 'faceit' )      { $faceit= 'FACEIT';      }
    if ( $value == 'matchmaking' ) { $matchmaking= 'Matchmaking'; }
}
```

Then i send it to my database like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( profilename,region, age, ranks, esea, faceit, matchmaking, textarea1 ) VALUES ( 
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['profilename'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['region'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['age'])}',
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ranks'])}',
$esea,
$faceit,
$matchmaking,
'{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['textarea1'])}')";


$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Unfortunately this code doesnt work. It just sends the rest of the values but not the string from the multipleSelect question. I don't know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As those fields are VARCHAR you need to wrap their values in quotes like this, this applies to any text type datatype used in a MYSQL Table

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( profilename,region, age, ranks, esea, faceit, matchmaking, textarea1 ) VALUES ( 
        '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['profilename'])}',
        '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['region'])}',
        '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['age'])}',
        '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['ranks'])}',
        '$esea',
        '$faceit',
        '$matchmaking',
        '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['textarea1'])}')";


$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
```